Are "lie low" and "keep a low profile" interchangeable?
In Oxford dictionary

lie low ​(informal) to try not to attract attention to yourself

In Cambridge dictionary

keep a low profile idiom to avoid attracting attention to yourself:
He's been in a little trouble recently so he's trying to keep a low
profile.

If we just look at their definitions from the dictionaries, they sounds the same in meaning.
But I feel like "lie low" seems to be used when you are in danger and want to avoid attention and "keep a low profile" is more like you are tired from your busy life and want quiet time for yourself.

The tired life thing is not accurate, for your information.

@Lambie, is that a typo saying "tired life"? why not "tiring life"?

"keep a low profile" is more like you are tired from your busy life = Is not right. And it's not because of the term tired life.

The two phrases are interchangeable in many cases, but "to lie low", as you suggest, means to go into hiding, or at least keep away from places and situations where you might be recognised. It's used in cases where the person is trying to avoid someone else, the authorities or some vengeful person or people.
On the other hand, "to keep a low profile" is to not draw attention to oneself. There is usually no sense of danger or pursuit. For example, in a job you would try to keep a low profile if you didn't want to be singled out for some special task, blame or praise.

After becoming drunk at my cousin's wedding, and insulting several people, my mother decided to lie low for a while. I could equally well write 'decided to keep a low profile'. They mean exactly the same thing in this type of situation.

@Michael Harvey, in that context, to lie low would probably be interpreted as to go to another part of the venue apart form other people, while keeping a low profile would simply mean avoiding any potential trouble.

@AaarghZombies - it would probably mean to stay away from family gatherings for a few weeks.

@MichaelHarvey I had a friend who, literally "lay low" when he got drunk. His phrase was "I've got to get under the table" at which point he would drop to the floor , crawl under the nearest table and pass out.

Isn't "lie low" also significantly more colloquial than "keep low profile?

@Edheldil I don't know but I would say "lay low".  "Lie low" reminds me of a joke my dad says: "he lies like a rug".

I don't know if it's a British-versus-American thing, but I regard "lay" for "lie" (as an intransitive present-tense verb) as a plain error. It's a back-formation from "lay" as the past tense of "lie". You lie on the sofa; you lay eggs or the table.

@Jimmy As Michael says, ‘lie low’ is the only unambiguously correct variant. Your comment is the first time I’ve ever heard anyone say that they think lie in the intransitive sense sounds wrong – it is the prescribed form, and usually accepted everywhere. Intransitive lay, conversely, is proscribed and still sounds wrong to many people, even though it’s very common and its use is still increasing.

@JanusBahsJacquet Do you think Bob Dylan's "Lay Lady Lay" would be improved as "Lie Lady Lie"?  I don't.

@MichaelKay It could be an AmE versus British thing but 'lie' is interchangeable for 'lay' in my experience, it just sounds inelegant. The usage of 'lay' this way apparently at least goes back to the 17th century.

@JimmyJames No, I don’t – that would diminish the alliteration, for one thing; I don’t think BTO’s You Ain’t Seen Nothin’ Yet would be improved as You Haven’t Seen Anything Yet either. They’re both clearly marked as colloquial/dialectal, which isn’t necessarily a bad thing in poetry and song, but I wouldn’t advise using such constructions if you’re writing a formal letter. (In Now I Lay Me Down to Sleep, the verb is transitive, so lie has never been possible.)

@JimmyJames "I Lay me down to sleep" is using lay as a transitive verb. "Me" is the object it is acting upon. But you are right that lay was used as an intransitive verb in Middle English. But by the 18th century it was already being considered incorrect, and it's only in the past few decades that it has started to become commonly used again. And even when lay was used intransitively, so was lie, so "lie low" would still have been correct usage too in those times.

One can "keep a low profile" generally, as one's modus vivendi, or one can do so in response to exigent circumstances, such as when a new boss arrives with instructions to thin the ranks and it seems best  not to stick your head up until you get a better sense of how draconian the new boss is going to be. The latter is more or less the same as "lie low", but not the former.

I think this is right. Or at least closer. "She always kept a low profile" makes sense; "she always lay low" doesn't. (At least to me in my dialect. I don't know if the same is true for all English speakers.)

Agree with @cfr, I think this hits the nail on the head. It sounds idiomatic to "lie low for awhile" but not as much to "keep a low profile for awhile". I feel like "lying low" connotes a transient state a bit more.

@NuclearHoagie 'keeping a low profile for a while' sounds fine to me. It just doesn't sound fine to 'lay low all your life'. 'keep a low profile' seems more flexible timewise than 'lie low'. as I say, in the idioms I'm familiar with. I imagine it could easily vary with dialect. 'He always lay low' doesn't convey a clear meaning to me, but it doesn't sound really weird. I just wouldn't be sure what was meant. (does the speaker mean he always kept a low profile, he was fond of lying low, he was always being laid low or something else?)

They are often used interchangeably, and the meanings you glean in your last paragraph are dependent on context.
For example: a celebrity could “lie low” for a while to stay out of the tabloids, and a criminal could “keep a low profile” after a big robbery to avoid capture.
